# XMADL: How to add a border with rounded corners to the pushbutton and change its color upon pressing?

Tags: mobile

I am using XMADL to write app for Android and iOS. I have a button defined in a screen.

```
<control type="PUSHBUTTON" x="39" y="24" width="50" height="8" appearance_name="blue_bkgrnd" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="Button 2"/>
```

The appearance used for this button is

```
<appearance name="blue_bkgrnd" font_family="Sans-Serif" font_name="Helvetica" font_size="3" font_color="#FFFFFF" background_color="#3A5894" alpha="255" justify="CENTER" font_style_bold="1"/>
```

How can I make the button with rounded borders and change its color upon pressing?

Answer (score 0):

To make the border rounded, add border related attributes to the appearance.

```
<appearance name="blue_bkgrnd" font_family="Sans-Serif" font_name="Helvetica" font_size="3" font_color="#FFFFFF" background_color="#3A5894" alpha="255" justify="CENTER" font_style_bold="1" border_color="#FFFFFF" border_width="3" border_radius="4"/>
```

This gives the PUSHBUTTON a border of width 3px, radius - 4px and color white.

To change the color to a different color on pressing the button, define a new appearance with background color that you want on press. Then assign it to the attribute on_pressed_appearance_name

New appearance:

```
<appearance name="blue_bkgrnd_tr_border" font_family="Sans-Serif" font_name="Helvetica" font_size="3" font_color="#FFFFFF" background_color="#50A6C2" alpha="255" justify="CENTER" border_color="#FF0000" border_width="3" border_radius="4" padding="0"/>
```

Add the new attribute “on_pressed_appearance_name”

```
<control type="PUSHBUTTON" x="39" y="24" width="50" height="8" appearance_name="blue_bkgrnd" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="Button 2"
```

on_pressed_appearance_name=”blue_bkgrnd_tr_border”/>

The appearance ”blue_bkgrnd_tr_border” will be applied when the user presses the button.

You can find more attributes about appearance [here](http://docs.appemble.com/ui_building_blocks.html#appearance).